# Необязательное поле формы. yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Имеется форма с некоторыми обязательными полями. Нужно одно из них сделать необязательным, а именно поле `email`.
**UserForm**

```
class UserForm extends User
{
    public $passwordConfirmation;
    protected $_password;

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();
        $rules[] = [['passwordValue', 'passwordConfirmation'], 'required'];
        $rules[] = ['passwordConfirmation', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'passwordValue', 'message' => Yii::t('web', 'Пароли не совпадают')];
        return $rules;
    }
```

**User**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['login', 'password_hash', 'auth_key', 'email'], 'required'],
        [['is_admin', 'is_active', 'manager_id'], 'integer'],
        [['login', 'password_reset_token', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['password_hash', 'auth_key', 'validation_code'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
        [['new_password', 'push_token'], 'safe'],
        [['email', 'login', 'password_reset_token'], 'unique'],
    ];
}
```

т.е. в классе `UserForm` нужно отменить поле `required` из базового класса `User`
Как это сделать?

P.S. 
подскажите, а такой вариант правильный?

```
class UserForm extends User
{
    public $passwordConfirmation;
    protected $_password;

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();
        $rules[] = [['passwordValue', 'passwordConfirmation'], 'required'];
        $rules[] = ['passwordConfirmation', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'passwordValue', 'message' => Yii::t('web', 'Пароли не совпадают')];
        unset($rules[0][0][3]);  //удаление email
        return $rules;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:
в User:

```
'required' => [['login', 'password_hash', 'auth_key', 'email'], 'required'],
```

В форме:

```
$rules = parent::rules();
$rules['required'] = [['login', 'password_hash', 'auth_key'], 'required'];
```

Но это в корне неправильно! У формы должны быть полностью свои правила валидации.

Comment: а подскажите, если класс `User`наследуют ещё другие классы, это новое свойство `$rules['required']` они также будут корректно определять? т.е. ведь обычно `required` пишется вторым свойством массива `[['login', 'password_hash', 'auth_key', 'email'], '<b>required</b>']`

Comment: подскажите, а такой вариант правильный? `unset($rules[0][0][3]);` т.е. чтобы удалить `email` после ` parent::rules();`